# ¿Cómo saber cual es el final de un string en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
cadena = "Este es un string en Python 3.6"
cadena_lista = []
acumulador = ""
for i in cadena:
    if i != " ": # este if es para agregar las palabras a acumulador
        acumulador += i
    if i == " ": # este para filtrar los espacios y separar los items en la lista
        cadena_lista.append(acumulador)
        acumulador = "" # aqui "limpio" la variable acumulador para usarla con el siguiente item. He de destacar que acumulador se queda con el ultimo valor "3.6", no lo guarda en la lista.
print("\n", cadena_lista, "\n")
```

---

El problema en este código está en que imprime solamente *['Este', 'es', 'un', 'string', 'en', 'Python']*, no imprime la ultima palabra o elemento del string: '*3.6*.' Esto es así porque el `if i == " ":` sólo agregará a la lista `cadena_lista` las palabras que estén separadas por espacios, al último elemento de la lista no tener un espacio al final no lo almacenará en la lista, sino que lo dejará guardado en la variable *acumulador*. Ahora bien, ¿existe alguna manera de saber el final de un string, de una secuencia o de resolver esto en Python, en mi caso Python 3.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta un último y simple paso:

Al terminar el `for`, si `acumulador` **no está vacío**, añadirlo a `cadena_lista`:

```
cadena = "Este es un string en Python 3.6"
cadena_lista = []
acumulador = ""
for i in cadena:
    if i != " ": # este if es para agregar las palabras a acumulador
        acumulador += i
    if i == " ": # este para filtrar los espacios y separar los items en la lista
        cadena_lista.append(acumulador)
        acumulador = "" # aqui "limpio" la variable acumulador para usarla con el siguiente item. He de destacar que acumulador se queda con el ultimo valor "3.6", no lo guarda en la lista.

# Añadimos esto
if acumulador != "":
  cadena_lista.append( acumulador );

print("\n", cadena_lista, "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas. Hay una manera mucho más sencilla de convertir una cadena a una lista en Python. Existe el método str.split(), el cual te convierte directamente "Este es un string en Python 3.6" en lista. Este método por defecto utiliza el separador como espacio, pero también puedes ponerle el separador que tú quieras con el argumento sep. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Juan, tu aporte es muy útil, es también eficiente, eficaz y sencillo, pues de este modo también resolví el problema, con un par de lineas de código; así:  
  
`cadena_lista = []`  
`cadena_lista = cadena.split()`  
  
Si lo imprimo con `print(cadena_lista)` la salida es:  
[__'Este', 'es', 'un', 'string', 'en', 'Python', '3.6'__]  
  
Gracias. Saludos Juan.

Comment: @orcaval Si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor, márcala como *aceptada*: el símbolo del *check* a la izquierda. Así, **ambos** ganais reputación. Un saludo.